# How can we change a list of email IDs into a unique numbers and also mask it in python

Tags: python, mysql, alteryx

I have a list of emails in a table and I want to give a unique number to each email and also whenever new emails comes into the table automatically it get assigned with a new unique ID. Come someone please help me into this?

Comment: Do you need this unique number as a primary key for your table or for some other purpose? More details would aid your cause.

Comment: yes I need this unique number as a primary key. Thanks, Booboo!

Comment: See [Using Auto_Increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Thanks Booboo, I'm familiar to your shared solution but I want this to get it done in Python. Please let me know if you know any way to get this done. Thank you